# SSIS script task issue

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

Using SSDT for Visual Studio 2013 am sending e-mail notifications via ssis script using SmtpClient class.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        SmtpClient v_EmailClient;
        string v_From = Dts.Variables["User::vFrom"].Value.ToString();
        string v_To = Dts.Variables["User::vTo"].Value.ToString();
        string v_EnvNameToSubject = Dts.Variables["User::vEnvNameToSubject"].Value.ToString();

        MailMessage v_EmailMessage = new MailMessage(v_From, v_To);
        v_EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        v_EmailMessage.Subject = v_EnvNameToSubject + "SSIS email notification"; 
        //Concatenation of variable with the standard message does not work

        v_EmailMessage.Body = "Message text";
        v_EmailClient = new SmtpClient("SmtpServer");
        v_EmailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        v_EmailClient.Send(v_EmailMessage);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

When I try to concatenate the variable v_EnvNameToSubject with the standard subject text does not work. I tried to use try catch block to find out the actual error message and that did not help either.

Comment: What type of error is returned? Is It inserted only: "SSIS email notification" in your Subject? The variable vEnvNameToSubject is canceled in your example...

Comment: I get the very generic DTS Script Task: Runtime Error pop up. I tried using try catch block and even that did not help. So, I am not sure what exactly is it that's making it fail.

Comment: That generic error, that does not respect try catch usually means that you mispelled your variable or are not referencing a third party tool correctly.  Try to comment out the dts.variable.... lines and see if you get past that error.

Comment: Is it failing to compile or failing to run? If it compiles and attempts to run, then try following this guide to find the exact source of the error you are getting. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136131.aspx

Comment: @Ben It compiles fine during runtime I have this error.

Comment: @JoeC If I do not use the variable v_EnvNameToSubject everything works as expected only when I try to use this variable I get error.

Comment: Try hard coding the value.  If it works with the Dts.Variables["User::vEnvNameToSubject"].Value.ToString(); commented out or removed then it must be a typo or scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, check your variables names (and cases) `vFrom` , `vTo` , `vEnvNameToSubject` because they are case sensitive.

**Second**, Try concatenating these strings another way *(Using `String.Concat()` Function or using a `stringbuilder`)*:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(v_EnvNameToSubject);
sb.AppendLine("SSIS email notification");
v_EmailMessage.Subject = sb.ToString();
```

*Or*

```
v_EmailMessage.Subject = String.Concat(v_EnvNameToSubject,"SSIS email notification")
```

**Third**, Check your variables scope and that they are added to the script task `ReadOnly Variables`